# Using Wireshark With Local Test Application

Tags: sockets, wireshark

I have written a small client server socket application. It is a proof of concept for some socket programming that I want to apply to a much bigger project.

For the moment I want to user wireshark to analyse the traffic that goes between them. They are both running on my local machine.

I have installed a loopback interface, and have tried to use wireshark with it.

No joy. Any ideas?

I have successfully analysed traffic between my machine and other machines no problems.

I have had a look here,

http://wiki.wireshark.org/CaptureSetup/Loopback

And I am not using the address 127.0.0.1 which they mention saying you can't capture traffic on 127.0.0.1

Thanks.

Comment: Read the Wireshark FAQ. There are known issues (and provided solutions) for dealing with lookback interfaces.

Comment: Thanks, but that is not working. I just added the link in above. The link above says to install a loopback interface, but it says 'in most cases that might not give results as expected either'. What does that mean? It is not working for me, so am I wasting my time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might try creating a virtual machine to run your application and using wireshark on it.

Comment: Thanks, I will do this if I cannot get Microsoft Network Monitor working. Making a VM will take a bit of extra time.

Answer (score 2):

Save yourself some grief and download [Microsoft Network Monitor](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=983b941d-06cb-4658-b7f6-3088333d062f&displaylang=en).
As good as Wireshark is on Unixen, Windows is a "special" case :)

Comment: It looks good, but it is not picking up the 'local' traffic. Any ideas? Do I need to use a loopback adapter? I tried it with and without. Still no joy.

Comment: Couldn't get it to work unfortunately. Wireshark with a VM did the trick.